# ASP.NET webAPI event confusion on hitting a non-existing route

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I have a simple ASP.NET webAPI project with just one route. When the route is called in httpModule BeingRequest is fired first followed by EndRequest as expected.

However when i hit the API with a route that doesn't exist i see the following behaivour in my HttpModule:

**BeginRequest Called ---> Begin Request Called ---> EndRequest (Response code 404) ---> EndRequest (Response Code 200)**

Below is the HttpModule:

```
using System;
using System.Web;
public class TestModule : IHttpModule
{
    public String ModuleName
    {
        get { return "TestModule"; }
    }


    public void Init(HttpApplication application)
    {
        application.BeginRequest += Application_BeginRequest;
        application.EndRequest += Application_EndRequest;
    }

    private void Application_BeginRequest(Object source,
        EventArgs e)
    {
        HttpApplication application = (HttpApplication)source;
        HttpContext context = application.Context;
        string filePath = context.Request.FilePath;

    }

    private void Application_EndRequest(Object source, EventArgs e)
    {
        HttpApplication application = (HttpApplication)source;
        HttpContext context = application.Context;
        string filePath = context.Request.FilePath;
    }

    public void Dispose() { }
}
```

and my controller:

```
    public class SampleController : ApiController
    {
        [Route("Test")]
        [HttpGet]
        public IHttpActionResult WriteLog()
        {
            //omitted code
            return Ok(true);
        }

    }
```

and my standard webApiConfig:

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // Web API configuration and services

        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

Problem is i'm logging the Response fields of each request to a database including the HttpContext.Current.Response.Status, but since the EndRequest event is raised twice i end up with 200 Status code even where the URL\route was not found.

Can someone explain the issue here? is the duplicate firing of BeginRequest an expected behaviour?

### UPDATE:

I've observed that this issue (BeginRequest being called twice) only occurs with attribute based routing. It does not happen when I use the conventional routing method:

```
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}"
            );
```

I cannot disallow the usage of attribute based routing so still need to fix the issue. Any pointers?

Answer (score 0):

Here's what i ended up doing to fix my issue where Response Status code of 200 was written to logs even where invalid route was called (404):

```
private void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
{       
    if (System.Web.Routing.RouteTable.Routes.GetRouteData(new HttpContextWrapper(HttpContext.Current)) == null)
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Response.StatusCode = 404;
    }
}
```